# How to make Index pages look like the rest of a website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, indexing

I have a WordPress site and am looking to add newsletter archives to it.

At the minute, I am downloading the HTML from MailChimp and uploading it to FileZilla. The index page is shown below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfuO3.png).

When people click the newsletters, they look perfect. However, how can I make the index page match the rest of the website? Ideally I would like to recreate this same directory on the site, without having to manually do too much. Can anyone advise?

Comment: If you're referring to an index page for your `newsletters` directory then you need to create one, since there is no page called `index.htm`, `index.html`, or `index.php`.  Without an actual file in there, your server is set up to display the directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory page on your current wordpress site and then link the html pages which can be held in a directory under your site's root folder.You can place all the html newsletters on a directory such as:

yoursite.com/newsletters/newsletter1.html

yoursite.com/newsletters/newsletter2.html 
and so on...

Now all you need to do is:

1) Create a new page on your wordpress site

2) Go to the editor and create the text necessary - You can use the visual editor on wordpress and do this such as:

**OUR NEWSLETTER ARCHIVE:**

1. Newsletter one (link this to: yoursite.com/newsletters/newsletter1.html)
2. Newsletter two (link this to: yoursite.com/newsletters/newsletter2.html)
3. Newsletter three (link this to: yoursite.com/newsletters/newsletter3.html)

Now using the above method, you can create a newsletter archive directory that will match your current site's style and still link html newsletters outside your site. and once they click through, they will browse through the newsletters easily.